# How can I find doc for -Dparameters for maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, configuration

As I know, we can set parameters for maven plugin by either put them in configuration section of pom.xml or -Dparameter in command line. I think -Dparameter will override the same one in the pom. I can find the available parameter list in the reference doc of the plugin. But how can got the -Dparameter list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the documentation for the plugin goal you want to configure.  The top part of the page lists the required and optional parameters.  If you scroll down the page (or click a parameter name) to view the parameter details, many of them have an "Expression" listed; that's the property you specify on the command line.

For example, consider the [jar:jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal as an example.  If I wanted to set the `forceCreation` flag to true, I could add `<forceCreation>true</forceCreation>` in the plugin config.  The [details](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#forceCreation) for the `forceCreation` property show the Expression as ${jar.forceCreation}, so I could add

`-Djar.forceCreation=true`

on my Maven command line to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks much. I found that there is no Expression for the property " skip"  in sql plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#skip). Does that mean I can not use -Dparameter to skip its excution?

Comment: No, it means you make your own expression.  Add `<skip>${maven.sql.skip}</skip>` to the plugin configuration.  In the `<properties>` section of the POM, define `<maven.sql.skip>` to be the default value (false in this case).  Then you may use `-Dmaven.sql.skip=true` to override the parameter when necessary.  (You may choose any expression you like, I chose one that is unlikely to conflict with other expressions..)